# What is the difference between read and pread in unix?

Tags: c, unix

What is the difference between the functions `read()` and `pread()` in unix?
When choosing between them, what points should I take into consideration?

I googled for the difference between them but without results.

Answer (score 44):

*Pread()* works just like *read()* but reads from the specified position in the file **without** modifying the file pointer.

You would use it when you need to repeatedly read data at fixed offset, for example a database index that points to individual records in file, to save on *seek()* calls.

Basically use *read()* if your data is sequential or *pread()* if you know, or can calculate offset at which to read.

Answer (score 22):

[From this `pread` link](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/man/html.2/pread.2.html),

> The atomicity of pread enables
> processes or threads that share file
> descriptors to read from a shared file
> at a particular offset without using a
> locking mechanism that would be
> necessary to achieve the same result
> in separate lseek and read system
> calls. Atomicity is required as the
> file pointer is shared and one thread
> might move the pointer using lseek
> after another process completes an
> lseek but prior to the read.

Answer (score 13):

Google gave me [`man pread`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/pread/).

If you `read()` twice, you get two different results, which shows that `read()` advances in the file.

If you `pread(`) twice, you get the same result, which shows that `pread()` stays at the same point in the file.

Comment: Not quite.  It shows that `pread()` either doesn't change the file position or doesn't care about the file position.  (As it happens, both are true.)

Answer (score 1):

read() starts reading the requested number of bytes from the current file offset whereas with pread(), you can specify the offset. This is useful in situations where one set of functions is reading through a file sequentially using the file pointer while another set is accessing specific data at the same time.