# Git Push to Network Drive: Cannot pread pack file

Tags: git, unpack, network-share

I'm trying to push locally to a shared repo on a network drive. I'm getting the following error:

```
:~/git push origin master
Counting objects ... done
Writing objects ...
Total ....
```

but then:

```
fatal: cannot pread pack file: No Permission
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To /networkshare/repo.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a unpack error)
```

The rights on the remote directory are like this:

```
:~/ls -all
drwxr-xr-x ndbd MyGroup  Date  Repo.Git
```

any clue?

Comment: What OS are you using, what kind of network sharing is this, and what git version are you using?

Comment: git 1.7.9.5, filesystem is mounted as fuse.smbnetfs (i.e. saba share), client is Linux, Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Could you check if the issue persists with git 2.8.4 (for upgrading, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24847953/6309)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message comes form [`builtin/index-pack.c#unpack_data`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f66975deb8402131fbf7c14330d0c7cdebaeaa2/builtin/index-pack.c#L547-L569).
It calls [`wrapper.c#xpread`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f66975deb8402131fbf7c14330d0c7cdebaeaa2/wrapper.c#L287) which wraps [`pread`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687275/6309) ([man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/pread/))

> If successful, the number of bytes actually read is returned.
>   Upon read-ing end-of-file, zero is returned.
>   Otherwise, a -1 is returned and the global variable `errno` is set to indicate the error.

The permissions state that only ndbd user has the right to *write* to that mounted folder. But read should work.
You need to check the permissions of the [git packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) created by the git push operation on the network drive to see if the same rights apply.

They are in `/networkshare/repo.git/objects`, `/networkshare/repo.git/objects/info/packs` and `/networkshare/repo.git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx`